# Is the "xmlns" in <html xmlns= ...> needed when the page is served as HTML 4.01?

Tags: html, xhtml, xml-namespaces

I like to serve the page as HTML 4.01, because XHTML is not really taken as XHTML in some browsers anyway, but [Facebook's OpenGraph meta tags](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) requires:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

but since the DOCTYPE of the page is not XHTML, does it matter if the `xmlns` are there, and should the page be made into DOCTYPE XHTML instead?

(actually, if the page is HTML, the `xmlns` is kind of confusing, as it is not really XML, but the Facebook page doesn't talk about how to add the meta tags in a page that is HTML 4.01)

Answer (score 3):

For HTML 4.01 Strict:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

For HTML 4.01 Trasitional:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

The xmlns stuff you see in the facebook example are XML namespaces and their purpose is to allow the developer to include custom tailored information to HTML documents.

Think of it like folders in a filesystem.

So when facebook declares:

```
xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"
```

They are defining a "folder" in which their custom tags/attributes/properties are stored, so:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
```

...where the important part is "fb:admins" is the same as having this on your hard drive:

```
/fb/admins.txt
```

which contains the USER_ID value.

So it's just a way to keep data organized and separated.

Hope this clears things up for you.

Comment: my question is, if the page is HTML, not XHTML (and therefore not XML), can the `xmlns` be there

Comment: The DOCTYPE declaration has nothing to do with the xml namespaces defined in the html tag, so the xmlns can be there. Check the imdb site source code and see how the xmlns attributes required by facebook are present in a HTML 4.01 Transitional document.

Answer (score 2):

It won't be valid HTML 4.01 if you add xmlns attributes, but it most likely won't affect the rendering.

I wouldn't use HTML 4.01 if I was you. HTML 5 is the new standard, and you should use it.

Comment: using HTML 5 and also the new tags such as `nav`?  Then have to worry about browser compatibility (e.g. IE 7)?

Comment: and even with HTML 5, how to handle those `xmlns`?

Comment: You don’t have to use the new tags in HTML5. You can probably just switch doctypes. It’ll make the `xmlns` attributes valid (I believe).

Answer (score 0):

Those are XML namespace definitions they exist as a way to avoid collisions in XML element names.

Since this is facebook's protocol, they are the ones that define the namespaces.

It has "nothing" to do with how the page is served.

Comment: so if the page is in HTML 4.01, then what should the `<html>` tag be? without the `xmlns`?